# При передаче массива строк в функцию строки равны NULL

Tags: c

Есть непонятная проблема по передача массива строк в функцию на языке Си.

Вызывающий код:

```
char str[33][40];
CreateCSV((char**)str);
```

Функция:

```
void CreateCSV(char** str)
{
    char strData[]= {'"','Д','А','Т','А','"',';','\0'};

    if(str[0x00] != NULL)
        strcpy (str[0x00], strData);
    else
        Console("СтрокаЗаголовка[0x00] == NULL");
}
```

Почему у меня `str[0x00] == NULL`? Ведь я явно создал 33 строки и зарезервировал по 40 символов под каждую.

Comment: А вам разве компилятор не выдаёт предупреждение на ваш cast?

Comment: без каста предупреждение)

Comment: @VladD ответите подробно или написать кратко?

Comment: @pavel ответ на такие вопросы: "читайте сообщения компилятора".

Comment: @alexolut думаю тут далеко не всем очевидно, почему нельзя делать этот каст.

Comment: @pavel: Я с телефона, написать ответ не выйдет. Так что пишите. :)

Comment: (char**)str  - на такой каст никак не ругается.

Comment: @VladD когда с телефона - сообщение надо начинать с фразы "алло" :)

Comment: @alexolut: Алло!

Comment: Я так понял все знают ответ но модлчат((

Comment: @Aldmi я сейчас напишу.

Comment: стал передавать так: (char СтрокаЗаголовка[][40])  Все рабоатет. но коментарии мне нужны, я думал что это идентично.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в кратце - используйте одинаковый прототип для объявления переменной и для параметров в функции и для strData. Это не самый красивый вариант, но он сработает

Вот как будет выглядеть Ваша программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void CreateCSV(char str[33][40])
{
   char strData[33][40]= {"\"","D","A","T","A","\"",";","\0"};

   if(str != NULL)
      memcpy (str, strData, sizeof(strData));
   else
      printf ("error\n");
}

int main (void)
{
   char str[33][40] = {'\0'};
   int i=0;

   CreateCSV(str);

   for (i=0; i<33; i++)
      printf ("%s\n", str[i]);

   return 0;
}
```

Обратите внимание на сл. нюансы - я использовал функцию копирования памяти а не строк "memcpy". И проверял на NULL имя str без указания сдвига. Это связано с тем, как язык Си представляет и обрабатывает многомерные массивы. Также при заполнении strData использовал двойные кавычки, иначе компилятор соединял буквы в одну строку, а не трактовал их как ряд строк с 1 буквой в каждой строчке.

---

Если в деталях и особенностях физики языка Си:
Массивы объявленные как

```
char str[33][40];
```

и как

```
char str**;
```

это совершенно разные вещи.

**char str[33][40];** - трактуеться как длинный одномерный массив глде все строки слеплены в одну одна-за-другой. Что-то ввиде
*"строка 1  \0\0\0\0\0...\0 строка 2  \0\0\0\0\0...\0 ....... строка 33  \0\0\0\0\0...\0 "* и размер такого массива будет равер 33*40*sizeof(char)=33*40*1=1320.

При объявлении такого массива, компилятор выделяет 1320 байт в стеке, и трактует переменную 'str' как указатель на эту длинную строку.

**char str**;** - это массив указателей на одномерные строки. Воспринимаеться компилятором как {*pointer_to_str1, *pointer_to_str2, ... *pointer_to_str33}, при этом сами строки лежат **вне** этого массива. Размер такого массива будет равен 33*sizeof(char*) = 33*4 = 132/

При объявлении такого массива, компилятор проводит несколько операций. Сначала компилятор выделит 33 независимых строки в стеке , затем создаст массив указателей и заполняет его указателями на эти 33 независимые строки.

Вот как будет выглядеть Ваша программа если strData объявить как char**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void CreateCSV(char str[33][40])
{
   char *strData[33] = {"\"","D","A","T","A","\"",";","\0"};

   if(str != NULL)
   {
      int i=0;
      for (i=0; i<33; i++)
         if (strData[i] != NULL)
         strncpy (str[i], strData[i], 40);
   }
   else
      printf ("error\n");
}

int main (void)
{
   char str[33][40] = {'\0'};
   int i=0;
   CreateCSV(str);
   for (i=0; i<33; i++)
      printf ("%s\n", str[i]);
   return 0;
}
```

PS
оба примера проверены на gcc

Comment: возвращаясь к Вашему изначальному вопросу - объявив str[33][40] Вы создали пустой массив, который вероятнее всего был автоматически заполнен компилятором нулями. Внутри функции вы  провели одно разименование, фунция ожидала увидеть указатель на строку, а получила первый символ еще пустого массива - вот отсюда и получился NULL

Answer (score 5):

Основная проблема - в преобразовании `(char**)str` тип `str` - `char (*)[33]`. Рассмотрим простую программу:

```
int main() {
    long a[10][10];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
       for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
          a[i][j] = -10000 - i*100 - j;
    cout << (long)a<<endl;
    cout << (long)a[0]<<" "<<(long)a[1]<<" "<<(long)a[9]<<endl;
    int **b = (int **)a;
    cout << (long)b<<endl;
    cout << (long)b[0]<<" "<<(long)b[1]<<" "<<(long)b[9]<<endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод: (у меня, он случаен)

```
140727855538752
140727855538752 140727855538832 140727855539472
140727855538752
-10000 -10001 -10009
```

Как видим, возникла проблема при доступе в `b[i]` мы ожидали что там указатель (int *) но там отрицательные числа. В b[0] содержится [0,0] элемент, в b[1] - [0,1] в b[9] - [0,9].

Почему так происходит. В многомерном массиве данные упакованы подряд:

```
[0,0][0,1]...[0,9][1,0][1,1]...[1,9]...[9,0][9,1]...[9,9]
```

При этом `a[i][j] <=> *(a + i*10 + j)`.

В массиве `int **` данные упакованы не подряд а (примерно) так:

```
b --> [0][1]...[9]
b[0] --> [0][1]...[9]
b[1] --> [0][1]...[9]
...
b[9] --> [0][1]...[9]
```

При этом они даже не обязаны лежать подряд. `b[i][j] <==> * ( *(b+i) + j)` Обратите внимание, что нужно уже 2 раза разыменовывать указатель. В этом смысле массивы `a[10][10]` можно считать одномерными, а остальное - удобство пользователя.

После преобразования происходит следующее (доступ в b[3][5] к примеру): (адрес a и b совпадает)

- берётся элемент по адресу (b + 3) смотрим в массив a --> это будет элемент a[3]
- берётся элемент по адресу ( a[3] + 5) в  a[3] какое-то значение, мы его пытаемся разыменовать - UB (а обычно SEG_FAULT)

Кстати компилятор не просто так запрещает прямое присваивание `int **b = a;` Имеет смысл читать эти предупреждения.

Если вам нужно передать такой массив в функцию, то есть разные варианты, как правильно написать прототип `func( char x[33][40])` первый размер можно не писать `func( char x[][40])` - самые простые.

Comment: картинок под рукой нет, у кого есть можете добавить)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Про упаковку данных подряд я знал и думал она всегда так идет, поэтому не сомневаясь передавал указатель на начало всей области. То-есть нужно передавать  указатель на массив в моем случае?

Comment: @Aldmi зависит от конкретной задачи и что будет в этой функции, пока туда можно передавать сразу `str[0]`

Comment: то-есть если я передам str[0], и в функции обращусь str[i] то я обращусь к i-ой строке?

Comment: `разЫменовать` только

Comment: напишите подробнее пожалуйста как передавать, как использовать, и сигнатуру метода

Comment: `func( char x[33][40]) последний размер можно не писать func( char x[33][])` только не последний, **а первый** (т.е. вот так `func( char x[][40])` будет верно)